# Serverless Graphql Lambda hard to understand this error

Tags: typescript, webpack, error-handling, graphql, serverless

im currently testing serverless in local, and i cannot find any information about this error im facing.

```
offline: [HTTP] server ready: http://localhost:3000 
offline:
offline: Enter "rp" to replay the last request

offline: POST /dev/graphql (λ: graphql)
Error: Root typing path /Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/.webpack/service/context.ts for the type context does not exist
    at Object.resolveImportPath (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/utils.js:410:15)
    at TypegenPrinter.printDynamicImport (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:136:40)
    at TypegenPrinter.printHeaders (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:84:18)
    at TypegenPrinter.print (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:73:22)
    at TypegenMetadata.<anonymous> (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenMetadata.js:109:128)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
offline: (λ: graphql) RequestId: ckmmzxdlg0002c2v1d2yxfhbo  Duration: 415.13 ms  Billed Duration: 500 ms

offline: POST /dev/graphql (λ: graphql)
Error: Root typing path /Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/.webpack/service/context.ts for the type context does not exist
    at Object.resolveImportPath (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/utils.js:410:15)
    at TypegenPrinter.printDynamicImport (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:136:40)
    at TypegenPrinter.printHeaders (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:84:18)
    at TypegenPrinter.print (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:73:22)
    at TypegenMetadata.<anonymous> (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenMetadata.js:109:128)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
offline: (λ: graphql) RequestId: ckmmzxhse0005c2v1aiec5ztn  Duration: 312.19 ms  Billed Duration: 400 ms

offline: POST /dev/graphql (λ: graphql)
Error: Root typing path /Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/.webpack/service/context.ts for the type context does not exist
    at Object.resolveImportPath (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/utils.js:410:15)
    at TypegenPrinter.printDynamicImport (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:136:40)
    at TypegenPrinter.printHeaders (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:84:18)
    at TypegenPrinter.print (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenPrinter.js:73:22)
    at TypegenMetadata.<anonymous> (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/dist/typegenMetadata.js:109:128)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/hydev/alttabgamestudio/serverless-server-hy/node_modules/nexus/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
offline: (λ: graphql) RequestId: ckmmzxlwf0008c2v1doakgt2q  Duration: 553.07 ms  Billed Duration: 600 ms
```

This is repetitive every 3~6 seconds.
There's no .webpack/service/context.ts, and i dont understand why it is looking for this but not auto-create.
I tried to create an empty context.ts in the path, but when i enter "serverless offline", it is deleted.

Does anybody know what is going on please?